# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive)

Tags: java

I got the below error while connecting to DB2 database using JDBC connectors.
Trying to Connect DB2 version 9.7.8 and Java version 1.8. Thanks in advance

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive). The specific key size 256 is not supported.

```
public class db2connect {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null; 
        try {             
              Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
              String url = "jdbc:db2://hotname:port/dbn :securityMechanism=13;";

              String user = "userxxx";
              String password = "pwdxxxx"; 

              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {           
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cause: Your Java version thinks that DH 256 is not safe any more. DB2 seems to think differently. Can you switch to a stronger encryption in DB2?

Comment: @jokster : Currently don't have the access the switch to stonger encription. Any other means?

Comment: Sorry. Don't know any way to make Java accept DH 256.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this kind of error is that you are using the standard restricted strength encryption in Java which is intentionally limited to meet export regulations.

You can download and install jar files supporting unlimited strength encrpyption from the Oracle web site.

See this link: [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)